# H-Bridge MOSFETS getting hot with no load

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I have the following circuit:
[image: Driver]

The circuit is working fine, but the problem is that when there is **no load**, the IRF9540 are getting hot. When they are in load, they are cold. For sure, I think it's a problem with the gate-source resistors.

I measured the voltage drop between G-S on the IRF9540 and I have the following values: -3.5V in no load and ~-11V in load.

I don't know how to tune the circit to remove this no-load heating, so I'm asking for your help. Thank you !

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say 'no load'?

Comment: Both switches are open (I forgot to open the left one in the picture).

Comment: Well then, none of your mosfets gates are being pulled all the way one direction or the other when you have the switches open. try removing r3 and r4, they are simply creating a voltage divider which can turn all of your mosfets on.

Comment: The bases on your NPNs are floating when the switches are open.  That might introduce noise to your FET gates and might be holding the FETs part way between on and off - not a happy place in this situation.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum isn't the gate voltage to high if I remove R3 and R4 ?

Comment: True, the IRF540 has a Vgs of +/- 20 V. You're using 24 V, right?

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum 12V.

Comment: Then you're fine. 20 Volts is the max. I'm willing to bet that is your issue. When your BJTs are off, the gates of the MOSFETs are held at 6 volts, and they have a threshold voltage of 4V (maximum). i.e. neither are turned fully off.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum ok then, but if I remove the resistors I have to connect the gate to ground also ? Because just removing the resistors resulted in no motor spinning when I closed the switches.

Comment: What do the gate voltages look like when the switches are open  and when closed?

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum my bad, the motor is working with both resistors out, but only in one direction. The G-S on N-type is ~6.5V, but the G-S on the P-type is the same, ~ -3.5 V. This is with switches open.

Comment: OK, I'm thinking about what could be happening there. Are the MOSFETs getting hot when your switches are open?

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum yes, they are heating.

Comment: Take those 2 resistors you removed and put them across the base-emitter of your NPN transistors. Make sure that they really are off when the switches are open. And your measurements don't add up: Vgs-Ntype + Vgs-Ptype should equal your supply voltage if you've got them connected as per your diagram.

Comment: @ ambitiose_sed_ineptum hit it on the head. Your resistive divider sets the gate voltage to 6 V if you turn off the transistors. Both upper and lower FETs will conduct and heat up.  You should remove R3 and R4, and change the relay (why a relay?) so it shorts the transistor base to ground rather than leave it floating. This would ensure that both N-Channel FETs are on and the P-Channels at off, this provides braking for the motor.

Comment: @JackCreasey normally, the signals will be PWM, so in the final scheme there will be no switches. Also, I'll put some pulldown resistors between the microcontroller and NPN base.

Comment: @PhilipCoandă: Since you have edited your question 17 months later I presume that the problem is still active. You should update your post further: fix the schematic which you admitted was faulty (and turn off the grid before taking a screengrab) and add in the various bits of information sprinkled through the comments.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble lies in the design of the gate driver.  When transistor Q5 is off, resistors R1 and R3 form a voltage divider that sets the gates of Q1 and Q3 at half the supply voltage, nominally 6V.  This is enough to turn on both FETs at the same time, causing a current to flow through them.  Since you are measuring only -3.5V instead of -6V, it appears that the current is large enough to cause the supply voltage to sag.  The reason the P-channels are getting hot is they have lower trans-conductance than the N-channels, and are seeing the majority of the voltage drop.

You need to re-design the gate driver so that only one of the FETs in each half-bridge can be on at a time.  The other FET must have its Vgs close to zero volts.