# MOSFET's getting too much heat up without any load

Tags: power, mosfet, resistors, h-bridge, heatsink

I am working on inverter, MOSFETs in h-bridge inverter goes heat up without any load attached. I also attached pull-up and pull-down resistor on it. here is my circuit duagram.
[image]

EDIT 
[image]

Sources of PMOS are connected to supply and sources of NMOS are connected to ground.

Output waveform and voltage are all good but have heating issue is not resolve.
Any suggestion or modification is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 9):

Your P channel MOSFETs are connected upside down: -

[image]

Notice the little diode symbols inside the MOSFETs? They will permanently conduct current and the MOSFETs will not switch off.

Comment: Sorry Andy aka I was upload the circuit image with some mistake, but in my actual hardware the circuit is correctly connected so that's why I am uploading the correct circuit diagram. But the problem is another.

Comment: Edit your question at the end and add the modified (corrected) circuit diagram. Don’t rewrite the question in case it makes my answer look invalid.

Comment: Ok Sir, I have 220 Ohm resistor on optocoupler input. For pull up and pull down 10k Ohm resistor is used. I think but not sure P-channels are getting hot in my circuit because they have lower trans-conductance than the N-channels, and are seeing the majority of the voltage drop. But what can I do ?

Comment: Only PMOS are heat up, NMOS are cool down.

Comment: @AbdulBasit the IRFZ44 has a significantly lower on resistance than the IRF9540 and if there is a shoot-through overlap then this will be the device to dissipate 3 or 4 times more heat than the N channel MOSFET. Shoot-through is caused when one MOSFET turns off and the other one turns on and there is a slight overlap in time when both are on. This takes a pulse of current from the power supply and dissipates heat as \$I^2R\$ loss. Driving with optos is not ideal because they will be slow to turn off the N channel device and not all that quick with the PMOS.

Comment: Means you say I drive the optocoupler less than 220 Ohms resistance ?. Because yet I drive the optos using 220 Ohms.

Comment: It's the MOSFET gate capacitance that "holds" the MOSFET on for longer than the opto is driving it. When the opto switches off you have maybe 1 nF gate capacitance and a 10 k resistor to pull it back to off. That is a CR time constant of 10 us and if you are operating at 10 kHz switching, that's 10% of the time that both MOSFETs might be conducting at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Can you say "shoot-through"? In addition to the problem that Andy pointed out, your MOSFETs are going to turn off much more slowly than they turn on. Have you allowed enough dead time between pulses to allow for this?

Also, are you really driving the optoisolators through 220k resistors? That's way too much resistance, and this will slow down the turn-on of the MOSFETs as well.

Comment: Sorry Dave Tweed I was upload the circuit image with some mistake, but in my actual hardware the circuit is correctly connected so that's why I am uploading the correct circuit diagram. But the problem is another.

Comment: OK, that addresses two of the three issues we raised. What about the 10k turn-off resistors?

Comment: I think issue is in pull up and pull down resistance value. here is a link almost same issue and same PMOS and NMOS used but have no idea about the changes of the circuit or/and value of pull up and pull down value. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270892/h-bridge-mosfets-getting-hot-with-no-load

Comment: If you want fast switching of the MOSFETs, you really want "totem-pole" (2-transistor) drivers on each one. For example the IRFZ44N has a total gate charge of 63 nC. If you want to switch that in, say 50 ns, you need a peak current of \$\frac{63 nC}{50 ns} = 1.26 A\$ (!). Your resistors only give you \$\frac{12 V}{10 k\Omega} = 1.2 mA\$, about 3 orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Not more fast switching just 50Hz.

Comment: In my case only PMOS are heat up, NMOS are cool down.

Comment: It doesn't matter how *often* you switch them, it's a question of how *quickly* they switch. With your 10k pullup/pulldown resistors, you need to allow something on the order of 100 us (or more) of dead time between turning off one transistor and turning on the other. Are you doing that?

Comment: I provide more than 100us delay between switching. Remmenber that IRFZ44N are NMOS and they are pull down with 10K resistor and they are not heat up instead of upper MOSFET's (PMOS IRF9540N). PMOS are pull up by 10k. According to you calculation, what can I do? Increase or decrease the resistance value ? Which resistance may I change?